# how can i observe interaction/communication between a process (user land) and a driver in windows

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, ipc, sysinternals

I tried to trace some known network API functions in some Sysinternals tools in order to observe/capture the interaction between a process and a driver (say for example arp.exe interaction with the network adapter driver?, what IOCTL is used etc.. )
I was wondering if there is any suitable way to do that besides debugging a program

thanks in advance!

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the function in your debugger if you already know its name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IRP Logger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/irp-logging) of Windows Driver verifier to get basic information about IRP coming to the driver. (Including from user space)